# send notification to ios and android using FCM Rest Api (New Versio)

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a `net core Back-End (3.1)`.

I created a page in which admin should enter title and description and pick a user to send a notification. 
I want to send notification `payload` to Apple devices and not to an android device similar to a custom notification.

there is a platform-specific notification in `Firebase Cloud Messaging` documentation .

However, I was not able to implement it .

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna only send the notification to Apple devices only. Then APNS Push notification push gateway will be suitable for you. [See here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/)

Certainly, FCM can also deal with this issue. You need to add the ApnsConfig to your request and send it to the FCM server.

If you cannot implement it, you need to mention more detail about your issue (trace log, exception info, etc.)

Comment: Tnx . After couple of days , finally understood what to do . As you said, i just had to use apnsconfig to implement it . Tnx again